# ggplot2 heatmap : how to preserve the label order?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm trying to plot heatmap in ggplot2 using csv data following casbon's solution in

http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/921/how-to-draw-a-csv-data-file-as-a-heatmap-using-numpy-and-matplotlib

the problem is x-label try to re-sort itself. For example, if I swap label COG0002 and COG0001  in that example data, the x-label still come out in sort order (cog0001, cog0002, cog0003.... cog0008).

Is there anyway to prevent this ? I want to it to be ordered as in csv file

thanks

pp

Comment: There are good answers below.  Here's a caution, in looking into this you may come across the 'ordered factor'.  Don't use it unless you know what you're doing.  Putting the levels in a particular order and using an ordered factor are not the same thing.  For example, ordered factors will cause some modelling software to default to polynomial rather than treatment effects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep the order directly from the csv file :

```
foomelt$COG <- factor(foomelt$COG, levels = unique(as.character(foo[[1]])))
```

Comment: In this case is not an issue, but there should be `unique(as.character(foo[[1]]))` in case of duplicate entries.

Answer (score 7):

If I recall, when calling factor(x) with the default levels argument, the levels are set as levels = sort(unique(x)).

You can override this action by setting levels = unique(x).

For example:

```
set.seed(1)
x = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE)
head(x, 5)
```

[1] "g" "j" "o" "x" "f"

```
levels(factor(x))
```

[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s"

[20] "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"

```
levels(factor(x, levels = unique(x)))
```

[1] "g" "j" "o" "x" "f" "y" "r" "q" "b" "e" "u" "m" "s" "z" "d" "k" "a" "w" "i"

[20] "p" "v" "c" "n" "t" "l" "h"

You can see that setting levels = unique(x) preserves the order of occurrence in the data.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try reordering factor levels before plotting?
e.g.

```
foomelt$COG = factor(foomelt$COG,levels(foomelt$COG)[c(2,1,3:8)])
```

(I can't try it right now, so I can't be sure that it works)

Comment: I don't think I could manually ordering since my data has around 100 and more point.